# Static method overloading

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, overloading

Suppose we declare a static method with same name in different classes. Is it possible?

If it is, then how and which function will be called?

```
class abc:
    @staticmethod
    def xyz():
        print 'class_abc'
class abc1:
    @staticmethod
    def xyz():
        print 'class_abc1'
class abc2:
    @staticmethod
    def xyz():
        print 'class_abc2'
```

So what's the output and how we can call different functions of different classes?

Comment: Your indentation is off for your first example.

Comment: It's actually overriding, which is different than overloading. But, where is that happening in this example?

Comment: Besides the identation problem, the question makes no sense since there isn't even subclassing in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You are having three classes with `xyz()` function in each class. But there is no relationship in these classes as they are not inheriting each other. So the answer is simple: *`xyz()` will be called of the class which is calling the method.*

For example: *`abc.xyz()` will call the `xyz()` function of `abc` class. Similarly you can make call to `ab1` and `abc2`'s function as: `abc1.xyz()` and `abc2.xyz()`.*

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding things. Classes introduce a separate namespace for themselves so, it is completely possible to create functions with the same name in different classes. These functions are not related in any other way other than their similar name.

Running `<classname>.xyz()` simply calls `xyz()` and prints the corresponding message.

Even if there was a relationship between the class, i.e a sub-classing relationship of the form:

```
class abc:
    @staticmethod
    def xyz():
        print 'class_abc'

class abc1(abc):
    @staticmethod
    def xyz():
        print 'class_abc1'

class abc2(abc1):
    @staticmethod
    def xyz():
        print 'class_abc2'
```

The most recent definition of `xyz` will override previously existing entries for it and the effect would be the same, that is `abc2.xyz()` would print `class_abc2`, `abc1.xyz()` prints `class_abc1` and so on.

Also, do note, you're using `Python 2.x` but aren't actually inheriting from `object`. This won't create a class in the sense most people are aware with today, take a look at *[What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)* to get a better idea of what this entails.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose we declare a static method with same name in different is it possible?

Yes

> If it is possible then how and which function will be called.?

It's possible because classes have their own scope. Python treats each static method in your example differently. And even if your classes where related, such as in @Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard example, the current method would override the last method.

Each method will be called uniquely because each class is unrelated in your example(except for all of the classes being of type class).